# Android Wear - Wake lock not waking up watch

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wake-lock

I am trying to make the watch vibrate at specific moments that are not at regular intervals.

I have no problem doing it when the watch's screen is on but it is not working when the watch screen dims out.

I have read a few questions on here and android developer's pages on WakeLocks and I think it's what I need... However it does not work for me. Below is my code, am I doing something wrong?

First, in my Manifest file, I have:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Here is parts of my code:

```
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onCreate(holder);

            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
            wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, TAG);
        }

        private void vibrate(int duration) {
            wakeLock.acquire();
            Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            v.vibrate(duration);
            wakeLock.release();
        }
```

The screen doesn't turn on and the watch doesn't vibrate... What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: How is this code getting run? Can you tell (e.g., from logcat) if your code is being run at the required interval at all?

Answer (score 0):

If your watch doesn't vibrate when you get a notification or you're not seeing notifications at all, check your watch after each step to see if notifications start working. try the [troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/androidwear/answer/6090188?hl=en-GB) steps below:

- Make sure that your watch isn't in Cinema mode.
- Make sure that you're getting notifications on your phone.
- Make sure that you haven't turned off (block) notifications for specific apps.
- Make sure that app notifications and system notifications on your phone are turned on.
- Check that your phone is connected to the Internet.
- Make sure that your watch is paired with your phone or tablet.
- Try restating your phone and your watch.
- Check that these apps are up to date: Google Play Services, Google, Android Wear.

Try to awake device by using the flag [`FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON).

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that unlike wake locks, it doesn't require special permission, and the platform correctly manages the user moving between applications, without your app needing to worry about releasing unused resources.

Another way to implement this is in your application's layout XML file, by using the `android:keepScreenOn` attribute:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:keepScreenOn="true">
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Using `android:keepScreenOn="true"` is equivalent to using **FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON**. You can use whichever approach is best for your app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the wake lock acquired for as long as you want the watch to stay interactive (and vibration to continue -- you must be in interactive to vibrate), but you seem to be releasing the wake lock immediately after acquiring it.

Acquiring wake locks can be risky, so if you're running that code from a watch face service (not clear from your snippet), start a transparent activity when acquiring your wake lock and release it when the activity dies -- this way, you are using the activity lifecycle as a means to stop the vibration and release a wake lock. This is something I implemented in the ustwo Timer Watch Faces (the watch face starts flashing and vibrating in interactive mode when the timer expires), and it's worked well.

Also, remember that to make vibration work, you need to declare the vibrate permission in the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```